# How I can add a custom Color to an TColorBox using the OnGetColors event?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm using the [OnGetColors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomColorBox.OnGetColors) event of the [TColorBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TColorBox) component, but I can't figure out how add new colors using the Items property of the item parameter of the Event.

```
procedure (Sender: TCustomColorBox; Items: TStrings) of object;
```

How I must add new colors to the TColorBox using the Items property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you must use the [`AddObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.AddObject) method of the Items object, like so  :

```
procedure TForm1.ColorBox1GetColors(Sender: TCustomColorBox; Items: TStrings);
begin
   Items.AddObject('clWebSnow',TObject(clWebSnow));
end;
```

Comment: What an ugly choice by the designer of that control. I wish they had made a TColorItems list type so you could call `items.AddColor( 'color name', value:TColor )`